# How to merge two nested object into one using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Hi I have been using AutoMapper to convert my objects, and now I'm trying to merge two nested objects into one, but I can't figure out how to do it.

**I have the following code:**

These are my source objects

```
class SourceSubItemA
{
    string subPropertyA;
}

class SourceSubItemB
{
    string subPropertyB;
}

class Source
{
    SourceSubItemA subItemA;
    SourceSubItemB subItemB;
}
```

Destination objects

```
class DestinationSubItem
{
    string propertyA;
    string propertyB;
}

class Destination
{
    DestinationSubItem destItem;
}
```

This is my Automapper configuration

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceSubItemA, DestinationSubItem>()
    .ForMember(dest => propertyA, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.subPropertyA));

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceSubItemB, DestinationSubItem>()
    .ForMember(dest => propertyB, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.subPropertyB));

// Probably I have to do something more here.
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.destItem, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.subItemA));
```

And finally I'm using the mapper by this way

```
Mapper.Map<Destination>(sourceObject);
```

The expected result must be a Destination object with a subitem with both properties filled.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, `Destination` is just a wrapper of `DestinationSubItem` that is the one that really needs to get the values from `Source`.

In that case, you could define a mapper from `Source` to `Destination` that puts in `dest.destItem` the result of mapping from `Source` directly to `DestinationSubItem`.

Here an example:

```cs
    Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.destItem, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<DestinationSubItem>(src)); 

    Mapper.CreateMap<Source, DestinationSubItem>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.propertyA, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.subItemA.subPropertyA)
      .ForMember(dest => dest.propertyB, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.subItemB.subPropertyB);
```

Comment: After a little fix to your answer `opt.MapFrom(src => src.subItemA.subPropertyA)` Now is working well, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah sorry, without autocomplete I missed that step. Answer updated :)

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers